# How to properly setup Angular2 and WebAPI 2.0 in Visual Studio 2015 and deploy to IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

My team and I are working on a new green field project and we will be using Visual Studio 2015.  Our client application will be entirely developed in Angular 2 and our api will be developed using ASP.NET Web API 2.0

Here is how I have structured my solution thus far:

**Angular2:** Using an ASP.NET MVC5 .NET 4.6.2 Empty Template

**WebAPI2:**  Using ASP.NET WebAPI 2 Template

[image: Solution Explorer]

I have the `Web API` project mapped to my Local IIS server:

[image: Web API IIS]

and I have the `Angular 2` application mapped to use IIS Express.

[image]

When I run this locally, I have to enable `CORS` on the `Web API` project to make these two applications work together.

[image: CORS]

and then in my `Angular 2` application I am having to hard code the entire URL:

[image: Hard Coded URL]

So my questions are this:

1. Is this the best way in Visual Studio to have a Angular 2 and Web API project setup?
2. Is it possible to not have to use CORS? This seems like it would be problematic not only for local developement but when going to Dev, Stage and Production!
3. Is it possible to architect this as such as that both the Angular2 and the WebAPI are living under the same IIS virtual directory so that in my Angular 2 project I can just call `const URL_CUSTOMER = 'api/Customers';` and not a fully qualified domain like I have it now?

I appreciate any guidance on best practices for architecting this solution better than I have it now! Thank you!

Comment: As @vidalsasoon states, it depends on what you want. If you want both the web api and the html5 client hosted on IIS, you can use ASP.NET MVC project template with Web API. Just delete all MVC related files and create your ApiController's and index.html. In this case CORS is not needed, because the client and service is hosted on the same address and port. If you want self-hosted services, your should do it like you have done it, and CORS is needed.

Comment: You can also take a look at this article: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have integrated the Angular within the WebApi project and did prove I can use the relative path and it worked.  I will discuss it with the team and see which route makes sense. Have it separated and use CORS or integrated and keep it relative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinions

> 1) Is this the best way in Visual Studio to have a Angular 2 and Web API project setup?*

Seems pretty good but I would use Local IIS for both your angular app and web api. ex: `http://myapp.localhost.com` and `http://myappapi.localhost.com`

> 2) Is it possible to not have to use CORS? This seems like it would be problematic not only for local developement but when going to Dev, Stage and Production!*

If you want different domains like it seems you do, you need to support CORS or else all your HTTP requests need to be JSONP which isn't good IMO.

> 3) Is it possible to architect this as such as that both the Angular2 and the WebAPI are living under the same IIS virtual directory so that in my Angular 2 project I can just call const URL_CUSTOMER = 'api/Customers'; and not a fully qualified domain like I have it now?*

You need to somehow set the API url in your web.config AppSettings (or any back-end settings) and then pass it along to your angular app. It's never going to be a relative path either locally or in production so you have to adapt to that.

Comment: After talking to my team we are going to keep the projects separate and implement CORS. Thanks for the feedback!